# allow multiple NULL values in unique key

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase

I am trying to allow for multiple NULL values in a unique key as allowed by ANSI SQL. E.g. in the below table I want to allow multiple NULL values in column `f1` and still have a unique constraint on it:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    i UNSIGNED INTEGER NOT NULL,
    f1 VARCHAR NULL
);
ALTER TABLE foo ADD PRIMARY KEY (i);
```

The naive approach fails:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo ON foo(f1);
INSERT INTO foo(i, f1)
select 1, null  union all
select 2, null;
```

… the above fails with:

> Attempt to insert duplicate key row in object 'foo' with unique index
>   'foo_f1_unq'

There's two approaches that apparently work for SQL Server:

### workaround #1: the null buster

This is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/191729/274677) but it doesn't work with Sybase ASE. The below fails:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    i UNSIGNED INTEGER NOT NULL,
    f1 VARCHAR NULL
);
ALTER TABLE foo ADD PRIMARY KEY (i);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo ON foo(f1) ;
ALTER TABLE foo ADD f1comp AS (CASE WHEN f1 IS NULL THEN CAST(i AS VARCHAR) ELSE 'non-null' END);
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT foo_f1_unq UNIQUE(f1, f1comp)
```

… with:

> Virtual computed column 'f1comp' cannot be referenced in any
>   constraints.

### workaround #2: create an index only on the non-null columns

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    i UNSIGNED INTEGER NOT NULL,
    f1 VARCHAR NULL
);
ALTER TABLE foo ADD PRIMARY KEY (i);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo ON foo(f1) WHERE f1 IS NOT NULL;
```

The above fails with a syntax error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

So my question is: how can I achieve this in Sybase ASE? Alternatively, is there a way to create a stored procedure that will be triggered on every insert or update of table `foo` and will raise an exception if a non-null duplicate value is found?